# using URL passed values, render different outputs in django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

**views.py**

```
class citydetailview(generic.ListView):
    model = country

    def get_queryset(self):
        city_type = self.kwargs['city_type']
        if city_type == 1:
            mytypes=city1.objects.all()
            ads=test1_ads.objects.all()
            context={'ads':ads,'mytypes':mytypes}
            return context
        elif city_type == 2:
            mytypes=city2.objects.all()
            ads=test2_ads.objects.all()
            context={'ads':ads,'mytypes':mytypes}
            return context
        elif city_type == 3:
            mytypes=city3.objects.all()
            ads=test3_ads.objects.all()
            context={'ads':ads,'mytypes':mytypes}
            return context
        return super().get_queryset()
```

I am trying to render the the output from model: country and from the conditional context from query set. And I am trying how to makeup the template for this class view.

To do so need your assistance :)

Comment: So what you have tried so far? and what was the problem with that?

Comment: Please show/mention the template code here to understand the problem well.

Comment: The above mentioned code is not rendering a template. Instead giving below exception.

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value: 
citydetailview requires either a 'template_name' attribute or a get_queryset() method that returns a QuerySet.